# Conditional Probability Question using Bayes

Tags: probability, statistics

A device for checking welds in pipes is designed to signal ($S$) if the weld is defective ($D$). The probabilities for the status of the weld and the response of the device are known to be: $\mathbb{P}(D)=.06$, $\mathbb{P}(S|D)=0.85$ , $\mathbb{P}(S|D')=.02$

Suppose a pipe is selected at random.

What is the probability that the device is defective given that the device signals (a defect)?

So I started out this problem by using the Bayes theorem doing $\mathbb{P}(D'|S)$, because this would mean the weld is not defective, but the device still signals. Is this the correct way to approach the problem, or should it be $\mathbb{P}(D|S)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need that probability of defective (D) given that is signals it (S).
So $P(D \mid S)$.

Do you have any trouble calculating it?

Comment: I have no problem calculating it. However, won't this give the conditional probability that the weld is defective, given that it signals a defect?

Comment: @user221636 yes.. isn't it exactly what you want to compute?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to compute is $P(D/S)$

According to Bayes' Rule: 
$$P(D/S) = \frac{P(S/D)*P(D)}{P(S)} \longrightarrow result 1$$

The only unknown is P(S). 
Apply Bayes' Rule on the given conditional probability of $P(S/D')$, you will have:

$$P(S/D') = \frac{P(D'/S)P(S)}{P(D')}$$
substitute $P(D'/S)$ by $(1 - P(D/S))$, get the value of $P(S)$, plug it back in result 1 and you get $P(D/S)$